# How can I hack a styles available in GWT theme?

Tags: css, gwt, gwt2

I need to hack some the styles in GWT Clean theme.

For eg. `.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs {`

```
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

The above style exists in GWT Clean theme.

The following is the hacked one,

`@external gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs;`

`.gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs {`
`background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF000;`

`padding-left: 1px;`
`padding-top: 0px;`
`top: 0px;`

```
width: 140px !important; }
```

In the UI i see the style in the Clean.css.
My hacked style is not applied. 
But  only the following lines are considered from my hacked Style

`top: 0px;`

```
width: 140px !important; `
```

These 3 lines are not applied

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF000;`
```

`padding-left: 1px;`

```
padding-top: 0px;
```

So can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed by adding !important; with all the properties.